# why sort function in javascript return wrong order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I use `sort` function in javascript to order array,here is my array

`var arr=[1118, 8446, -9046, -1719, 41, 279, 11, 2047, 3855, 4925, 7380, 8477];
arr.sort((a,b) => {return a-b > 0});`

but I got the wrong order ,here is the result,

`[11, 1118, -9046, -1719, 41, 279, 2047, 3855, 4925, 7380, 8446, 8477]`

here is the screenshot.So where am I wrong？

[image]

Comment: You need [`arr.sort((a, b) => {return a - b});`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Creating_displaying_and_sorting_an_array) (or simply `arr.sort((a, b) => (a - b));`). `return a - b > 0;` doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: Because you are not implementing the sort callback correctly. Please read [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description).

Comment: @Xufox thanks.my fault.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If compareFunction is supplied, the array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function. If a and b are two elements being compared, then:

If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than b, i.e. a comes first.
If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
If compareFunction(a, b) is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.
compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.
So, the compare function has the following form:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr=[1118, 8446, -9046, -1719, 41, 279, 11, 2047, 3855, 4925, 7380, 8477];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b; // ascending
});
console.log(arr);


arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b - a; // descending
});
console.log(arr);
```